# Should I use try-catch in test case?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, mocha.js, jestjs

I am thinking a problem. Here is a sample:

`index.ts`

```js
async function getUserById(id?: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (id) {
      const user = { id };
      resolve(user);
    } else {
      reject(new Error('user id is required'));
    }
  });
}

export { getUserById };
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { getUserById } from './';

const coin = () => Math.random() > 0.5;

describe('should throw an error test suites', () => {
  const testCount = 1000;

  for (let i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
    it(`t-${i}`, async () => {
      const id = coin() ? 1 : 0;
      try {
        const user = await getUserById(id);
        expect(user).toEqual({ id });
      } catch (error) {
        expect(error.message).toBe('user id is required');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

test results:

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1000 passed, 1000 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.637s
```

As you can see, I dynamic generate a lots of test cases. The problem is the test cases will always pass in this case. I think it's not correct to test the `correct` part and `exception` part together. Am I correct?

When should I use `try-catch` in test cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `try-catch` in test code is not a problem as such.  In fact, you even need to do it if in your test code you want to verify if the system-under-test (SUT) throws an expection as expected.

Your particular example, however, does some things in the test code which have disadvantageous consequences.  One thing is that your test code merges tests for two different aspects (success scenario and failure scenario) into one test function.  One of the disadvantages is, that this complicates the test code and makes it at times difficult to understand which part of the setup is necessary for which test.  You used `try-catch` for merging the tests, but not `try-catch` is the problem, but the merging.

And, in fact, this merging actually has lead you into a trap: Your merged tests do not work properly.  For example, you select an `id` randomly.  An `id` of 1 should result in a proper `user` to be delivered.  However, you do not really test that: If your SUT mistakenly *always* throws an exception, you will consider this as a successful test.

Secondly, you run 1000 tests, but effectively only test two scenarios (aspects).  Therefore, the 1000 tests don't buy you anything.  Quite the contrary: The extra complexitly can even mean you mistakenly (because of a bug in the selection of the scenario) do not test both scenarios.  Or, that by coincidence always one scenario is chosen (unlikely, admitted).  In any case, you waste time for executing 1000 tests for the effective value of only 2 aspects tested.

Comment: Is that means I should test the certain exception part in one test case and test correct part in a new test case. Shouldn't test both of them in one test case?

Comment: Yes, that are two different aspects of your code.  Each unit-test should ideally focus on one aspect.

Comment: Thanks. Which means before testing the code, you should already know it will be correct or wrong? Am I right?

Comment: When writing the test you will not know if the test will succeed, but you should certainly know what is the criterion for a succeeding test.  In your case, if you call the code with an id=0, then the success criterion is that an exception is thrown.  If you call the code with an id!=0, then the success criterion is that a user is returned with that id (simplified - probably there exist failure cases also for id!=0, but from your example this was not apparent).

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing whether your application throws an expected Exception at a given time, you should use a try-catch block to trigger the Exception, and evaluate it.

I don't think that you can say that there is any ruleset for when to use them besides that. of course that depends on your goal, and your coding style, but then we are approaching an opinion based answer, which is slightly off-topic for this site ;-)

Comment: I think I should test the certain `exception` part in one test case and test `correct` part in a new test case. Shouldn't test both of them in one test case.

Comment: Again, that depends on your preference. some people like few, comprehensive testcases (i do not, it makes it difficult to see exaclty what is failing), others prefer isolated testcases. if you look at Test Driven Development, the idea is that you define your testcase first, and then code/recode in order to make your testcases pass. but if you collect everything n a single testcase, you will lose the overview at some stage.